# manifest tagged by "latest" is not found

Tags: jss, docker

I am trying to run JSS  with Sitecore xp1 in Docker.

I am referencing the following URLs:

1. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/add-sitecore-modules.html
2. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/sitecore-module-reference.html

But I am unable to build the images:
**Error:**

```
COPY --from=scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-headless-services-xp1-assets C:\module\db C:\resources\jss_data
invalid from flag value scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-headless-services-xp1-assets: manifest for scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-headless-services-xp1-assets:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "latest" is not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Headless module is not tagged with `latest`, please refer to https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering.aspx and later to
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.json in order to find your proper version Tag (search for `sitecore-headless-services-xp1-assets`), then add it to your config. For Sitecore 10.2:

```
COPY --from=scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-headless-services-xm1-assets:20.0.2.00545.395-10.0.17763.3650-1809 C:\module\db C:\resources\jss_data
```